# Move row loop not working in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google appscript that is frustrating me. It is basically a modification of the copy row script, now made to loop over a specific column for that value. I want the row to move to the next sheet if the value in that column is greater than the value to watch ie. 3 in this case.

I've modified it best I can but don't understand why it isn't executing. Could anyone help me sift through the code and find out what I am missing?

```
function moveAllRightRows(){
//this script is supposed to move every row in Sheet1 to Sheet2 
//if the value in a cell is greater than 3

  var columnNumberToWatch = 9; //column where value will be filled
  var valueToWatch = 3; //integer that determines trigger value
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Sheet2";      

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var row = 1;
  var len = sheet.getRange(1 , columnNumberToWatch, sheet.getLastRow() - 1).length; 
  var range = sheet.getRange(row,9,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1); //get column 9 from row 1 to the end

  for (row ; row <len ; row++){

  if (range.getValue() > valueToWatch) { //if the value in the column is greater than 3

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
  sheet.deleteRow(row);


  }
}
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Try debugging to provide us with more information.

Comment: As a note of caution, you are writing code that accesses content by index and also modifies future content indices while iterating. This is easy to do incorrectly. Additionally, you have not provided information about how your function is called (or even what it is named...). I strongly recommend you edit your post to 1) provide the complete function definition, 2) Fix the indentation errors in your post (there's a preview...), and then 3) carefully explain each line of your code and its purpose to some object near your computer (see "code duck"). We'll be happy to help after you do this.

Comment: @tehhowch I've made the modifications. Thanks for pointing this out. Hope they make the question easier to understand.

Comment: @I'-'I I don't understand what you mean, could you clarify?

Comment: @josephoun Thanks for looking through it: there are no errors in the console. The output runs but does nothing.

Comment: @Sam can u provide me a jsfiddle link and i will try to help with pleasure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Couple of things,I believe are wrong with your script:

- Length property can only be called upon arrays/strings and not on objects.
- `range.getValue()` only returns the top left cell in the given range. So, You are not looping through all the cells in the column, but only the first cell in the given column. So, Through each iteration of the loop (row++) , only the first cell is checked (cell I1) , whether it is greater than 3. Use `getValues()` instead.
- Deleting Rows will cause row numbers to change. If row 4 is deleted, row 5 will become row 4. So,To avoid confusion, We reverse the loop and do a Bottom up approach(starting from the last row).
- A better option would be get a array and setValues() instead of moveTo()

#### Modification points:

Try modifying

From

```
    var len = sheet.getRange(1 , columnNumberToWatch, sheet.getLastRow() - 1).length; 
    var range = sheet.getRange(row,9,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1); //get column 9 from row 1 to the end
    for (row ; row <len ; row++){
      if (range.getValue() > valueToWatch) { //if the value in the column is greater than 3
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
      var  targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
      sheet.deleteRow(row);
```

To

```
 var range = sheet.getRange(row,9,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues(); //get  Values of column 9 from row 1 to the end
 var len = range.length;
 var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
 for (row=len; row> 0 ; row--){
  if (range[row-1][0]> valueToWatch) { //if the value in the column is greater than 3
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1,sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
      sheet.deleteRow(row);
     }}
```

Comment: You are a genius! Just reading through your code has taught me so much! Thanks! When I grow up I want to code like you :)

Comment: Haha. Okay. Will work on my skill level. I'd love to know how you upskilled to get to where you are.